# KL divergence between two multivariate gaussians where $p$ is $N(\mu, I)$

Tags: normal-distribution, bayesian, means

We know if we try to get $D_{KL}(q||p)$, where $p$ is a standard normal distribution, so mean is 0, variance is the identity matrix, and $q$ is a multivariate normal distribution, it can be calculated as

$$-0.5 * (1 + log \space \sigma^2 - \mu^2 - \sigma^2)$$

From [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/318748/deriving-the-kl-divergence-loss-for-vaes), I've seen it's broken down like this:

$$\begin{align}
\mathfrak{D}_\text{KL}[q(z|x)\mid\mid p(z)] 
&=
\frac{1}{2}\left[\log\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|} - n + \text{tr} \{ \Sigma_2^{-1}\Sigma_1 \} + (\mu_2 - \mu_1)^T \Sigma_2^{-1}(\mu_2 - \mu_1)\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\log\frac{|I|}{|\Sigma|} - n + \text{tr} \{ I^{-1}\Sigma \} + (\vec{0} - \mu)^T I^{-1}(\vec{0} - \mu)\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[-\log{|\Sigma|} - n + \text{tr} \{ \Sigma \} + \mu^T \mu\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[-\log\prod_i\sigma_i^2 - n + \sum_i\sigma_i^2 + \sum_i\mu^2_i\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[-\sum_i\log\sigma_i^2 - n + \sum_i\sigma_i^2 + \sum_i\mu^2_i\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[-\sum_i\left(\log\sigma_i^2 + 1\right) + \sum_i\sigma_i^2 + \sum_i\mu^2_i\right]\\
\end{align}$$

Am I right that to earn what I want (which is $\mu_2$ isn't 0), I need to change this to:

$$\begin{align}
\mathfrak{D}_\text{KL}[q(z|x)\mid\mid p(z)] 
&=
\frac{1}{2}\left[\log\frac{|\Sigma_2|}{|\Sigma_1|} - n + \text{tr} \{ \Sigma_2^{-1}\Sigma_1 \} + (\mu_2 - \mu_1)^T \Sigma_2^{-1}(\mu_2 - \mu_1)\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[\log\frac{|I|}{|\Sigma|} - n + \text{tr} \{ I^{-1}\Sigma \} + (\mu_2 - \mu_1)^T I^{-1}(\mu_2 - \mu_1)\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[-\log{|\Sigma|} - n + \text{tr} \{ \Sigma \} + (\mu_2 - \mu_1)^T(\mu_2 - \mu_1)\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[-\log\prod_i\sigma_i^2 - n + \sum_i\sigma_i^2 + \sum_i(\mu_2 - \mu_1)^2_i\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[-\sum_i\log\sigma_i^2 - n + \sum_i\sigma_i^2 + \sum_i(\mu_2 - \mu_1)^2_i\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[-\sum_i\left(\log\sigma_i^2 + 1\right) + \sum_i\sigma_i^2 + \sum_i(\mu_2 - \mu_1)^2_i\right]\\
\end{align}$$

How does the equation change if $\mu_2$ isn't 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take $|\Sigma| = \prod_i \sigma_i^2$ which is not true for general covariance matrices $\Sigma$. Without making explicit assumptions on $\Sigma$, your expression is incorrect, and the best we can hope for is:

\begin{align*}
\text{KL} (N(\mu_1, \Sigma) \| N(\mu_2 , I))
&= \frac{1}{2} \left [ 
\log \frac{|I|}{|\Sigma|} + \text{tr}(\Sigma) + \|\mu_2 -\mu_1\|^2_2 - n
\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left [ 
-\log |\Sigma| + \text{tr}(\Sigma) + \|\mu_2 -\mu_1\|^2_2 - n
\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left [ 
-\log |\Sigma| + \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n (\mu_{2i} -\mu_{1i})^2 - n
\right]\\
\end{align*}

The question you link to in your post assumes $\Sigma$ is diagonal, in which case your final expression looks correct to me.

Comment: In my case its 3 dimensional matrices with the same shape

Comment: @GergőHorváth the dimension isn't important, it's whether or not they are diagonal or not

Comment: I don't think it's diagonal, it's coming from a machine learning algorithm, so the numbers are random

Comment: @GergőHorváth well then the best you can do is the expression in my answer.. if you provide more details i'd be happy to help but i think this is the most I can say with the information provided